# How to label barplots with the row that the data is from?

Tags: r, label, bar-chart, par

I have a csv file where there are 9 columns and 15 rows. I was told to create a barplot of each of the rows using the par function. Here's my code

```
par(mfrow=c(3,5))
> barplot(c(as.matrix(matnew[1,])), main='Gene Expression', xlab='Gene Name', ylab='Length',col=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3), names.arg=names(matnew), barplot(c(as.matrix(matnew[2,])), main='Gene Expression', xlab='Gene Name', ylab='Length',col=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3), names.arg=names(matnew), barplot(c(as.matrix(matnew[3,])), main='Gene Expression', xlab='Gene Name', ylab='Length',col=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3), names.arg=names(matnew), barplot(c(as.matrix(matnew[4,])), main='Gene Expression', xlab='Gene Name', ylab='Length',col=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3), names.arg=names(matnew), barplot(c(as.matrix(matnew[5,])), main='Gene Expression', xlab='Gene Name', ylab='Length',col=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3), names.arg=names(matnew), barplot(c(as.matrix(matnew[6,])), main='Gene Expression', xlab='Gene Name', ylab='Length',col=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3), names.arg=names(matnew), barplot(c(as.matrix(matnew[7,])), main='Gene Expression', xlab='Gene Name', ylab='Length',col=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3), names.arg=names(matnew), barplot(c(as.matrix(matnew[8,])), main='Gene Expression', xlab='Gene Name', ylab='Length',col=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3), names.arg=names(matnew), barplot(c(as.matrix(matnew[9,])), main='Gene Expression', xlab='Gene Name', ylab='Length',col=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3), names.arg=names(matnew), barplot(c(as.matrix(matnew[10,])), main='Gene Expression', xlab='Gene Name', ylab='Length',col=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3), names.arg=names(matnew), barplot(c(as.matrix(matnew[11,])), main='Gene Expression', xlab='Gene Name', ylab='Length',col=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3), names.arg=names(matnew), barplot(c(as.matrix(matnew[12,])), main='Gene Expression', xlab='Gene Name', ylab='Length',col=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3), names.arg=names(matnew), barplot(c(as.matrix(matnew[13,])), main='Gene Expression', xlab='Gene Name', ylab='Length',col=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3), names.arg=names(matnew), barplot(c(as.matrix(matnew[14,])), main='Gene Expression', xlab='Gene Name', ylab='Length',col=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3), names.arg=names(matnew), barplot(c(as.matrix(matnew[15,])), main='Gene Expression', xlab='Gene Name', ylab='Length',col=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3), names.arg=names(matnew))))))))))))))))
```

and this gave me 15 barplots with data from each row. I wanted to know if there was a way where I could label each barplot with which row it is meaning barplot 1 is row 1, barplot 2 is row 2 (kinda like a subehading).

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason to write out 15 separate calls to `barplot`.

This is an appropriate case for using a `for` loop:

```
# make simulated data since you did not provide any
my_matrix <- matrix(sample(10, 135, replace = TRUE), ncol = 9, nrow = row_count)

par(mfrow = c(3,5))

for (i in 1:nrow(my_matrix)) {
  barplot(
    my_matrix[i,],
    main = 'Gene Expression',
    sub = paste("Row", i),
    <your other arguments>
  )
}
```

You can also use whatever `*apply` family function you are most comfortable with, e.g.:

```
invisible(
  vapply(
    1:nrow(my_matrix),
    FUN = function(i) {
      barplot(
        my_matrix[i,],
        main = 'Gene Expression',
        sub = paste("Row", i),
        <your other arguments>
      )
      TRUE
    },
    FUN.VALUE = TRUE
  )
)
```

Comment: Thank you for letting me know how to use the for loop. However, this question was a part of an assignment where I had to write the 15 barplots using  the par() function and then 15 barplots again using the for() function. Would my original code be right then for the par() function?

Comment: `par()` and `for` are unrelated. `par()` controls graphics device parameters. `par(mfrow = c(3,5))` specifies that the next 15 `*plot()` calls should be written to the same device in a 3x5 grid. `par()` controls display parameters **only**. `for` or `*apply()` are different ways to do multiple similar operations. Your original code "works" but isn't idiomatic. There's no reason to use a call to `barplot()` as an argument of another plot function. Your nested calls do get evaluated, but only because barplot() evaluates any arbitrary argument (poor design on the part of `barplot()`!)